# How do you add extra html after an element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm aware of [jQuery's append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) which appends html inside the selected element.  I want to add more html after the selected element.  For instance:

```
<a href="/somewhere/">Somewhere</a>
```

I want to add the html `<h3>Hello</h3>` after the above to become:

```
<a href="/somewhere/">Somewhere</a>
<h3>Hello</h3>
```

How can you achieve that in jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[after](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Answer (score 0):

To address your problem, here is the full code:

```
$('a[href=desired_url]').after('<h3>Hello</h3>');
```